# what is the Big O( ) order of std::queue::size?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, big-o

The `std::queue` class is unclear as to the complexity of the `size` member function. It appears to be based on the data structure implementation used at the time.

One would *assume* that `size` would be `O(C)`, but it's totally possible for it to be `O(N)`. Obviously, I can keep my own size, but I would rather just call `size`.

(Question modified): since `deque` is the default container, what is O ( ) of std::deque::size()?

Comment: All standard containers' `size()` functions must be constant time. See  [container.requirements.general].

Comment: C++11 mandates O(1) for size() of all containers. I believe that was not mandated before, though.

Comment: @chris Not `forward_list`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Good point. The reference (and the standard) even explicitly says it meets every requirement but `size()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up the very good answers here:

- C++11: `O(1)` (*@Jeffrey*)
- C++98: unenforced, need to do experimentation based on the container class
- C++98 with default container: the    default    container for std::queue
  is std::deque, which calculates size    by    subtracting two
  iterators, which is ***not*** `O(1)`, but at least `O(C)`. (***@juanchopanza***)

Thus, if you need to ensure O(1)-ness of size() in C++98, you must keep your own count.

If I might, I would like to step on my soap box and thank the C++11 group for closing this horrendous specification hole. Many languages/libraries (such as Scala) take great pains to define the BIG-O of an operator. Given that the main use case of C++ is performance, I find this lack of specification amazing. It is completely unacceptable that one should have to inspect header code to determine performance characteristics of ***std*** classes.

Comment: I share your sentiment.

Answer (score 9):

*At least* since C++11, the complexity of `std::queue::size` [is *constant*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/size): O(1).

This is guaranteed by the fact that the underlying container of `std::queue`, as per §23.6.3.1/1, have to fit the requirements of [`SequenceContainer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer), that inherits the requirement of [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container), which, in turn, as per §23.2.1, requires the member function `size` to have a constant time complexity.

Comment: I am glad to hear about that, but would like to know more about this that I just found.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808916/stdqueuet-listt-size-is-slow-in-on

Comment: I don't think that is guaranteed.

Comment: Precisely. I am a bit troubled by this. So let me be more explicit:

What is the order of size() of:

std::queue<SomeClass>

In other words, the default backing store.

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos In that case, it is constant time.

Comment: @Praetorian Typo. Anyway, there is an exception.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, `forward_list` is an odd duck. But it doesn't meet the requirements for underlying container for `queue` anyway because it doesn't have `push_back`'

Answer (score 1):

`std::queue::size` is specified exactly in C++11 23.6.3.1/1:

```
size_type size() const { return c.size(); }
```

where `c` is a `protected` data member whose type is that of the second template parameter. *Ergo*, its complexity is exactly that of the `size` member function of said template parameter. The default is `std::deque<T>` - where `T` is the first template parameter passed to `std::queue` - which has the default O(1) complexity requirement common to all containers unless otherwise specified (per Table 96 in 23.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is constant O(1).

Constant (calling size on the underlying container).
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/size/

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the implementation you use, and it's best to check this yourself. Hopefully inspecting header files are not that hard. Even though newer standards mandate that it should be constant, that's the only way to be sure. For one example worth noting, gcc's libstdc++ still has O(n) for `std::list`.

Comment: Wow. When it comes to libraries, especially the STD, "use the source Luke" is not a happy answer. However, glad to hear that in C++11 things are a bit more stringent.

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos To clarify: whether `size()` in a default queue is constant time **is not** implementation dependent. The standard mandated the default container used to be `std::deque`, and `std::deque::size` is constrained to be constant time.

Comment: Indeed it's not. However, to quote one DMV handbook loosely, 'the fact that drivers are not allowed to run over you doesn't really prevent them from doing so'.

Comment: On the other hand, who would want to use an implementation that is non-standards compliant on such a basic level?

Comment: I believe C++03 never required this. And the question did not refer to either any specific standard or any specific implementation. So the only answer I could have provided in that case is that nuking from the orbit is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @juanchopanza lots of people. Pretty much anyone who uses GCC. It's not the only noncompliance in libstdc++. (their std::string still uses COW too)